# Sony SmartWatch - How to get ALL touch points

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I understand that OnTouch is called every time there is a touch event (`TOUCH_ACTION_PRESS`, `TOUCH_ACTION_LONGPRESS`, or `TOUCH_ACTION_RELEASE`). However, when a user touches the screen, there might be many touch points between the start and end points (i.e., between `PRESS and RELEASE points`). How can I find all those touch points in between?
Is there anything like `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` for `SmartWatch`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487819/android-smartwatch-respond-to-a-long-press-event

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment! I have tried those. PRESS and RELEASE give the first and last touch points and it seems LONGPRESS gives the same point that PRESS gives. The only difference is that LONGPRESS action is triggered only if the user has touched the screen for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current implementation of the SmartWatch firmware, you cannot get the touch points through a whole touch gesture. Instead, as you say, you will get the start point coordinates (PRESS) and the end point coordinates (RELEASE). A SWIPE event will also be broadcasted, but this event only indicates the direction of the swipe, i.e. no coordinates.

Comment: Any chance, it will be supported in the next version of the firmware?